# How can I add es6-promise into babel blacklist?

Tags: ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs

In https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-js#custom-build

I saw '--blacklist=es6.promise', but in bablelrc, It does'nt work.

---

ReferenceError: Unknown transformer es6.promise specified in blacklist

Answer (score 0):

In Babel, `require('babel/polyfill');` will load the default polyfill (core-js) with promise support included. The page you linked to that describes `--blacklist=es6.promise` is for `core-js`'s packaging scripts, not for Babel. That core-js documentation assumes that you'd use babel as normal, but instead of doing `require('babel/polyfill')`, you would instead `require()` your own custom build of core-js, as built using the command on the page you linked to.